# Procedure entry point __printf__ could not be located in the dynamic link library libintl-8.dll

Tags: objective-c, mingw, gnustep

When compiling Objective-C with GNUstep/MinGW I get the following error:

```
The procedure entry point __printf__ could not be located in the dynamic link library libintl-8.dll.
```

Windows 7/64-bit.  File version on libintl-8.dll is 0.18.1.

Is the compiler using the right file?

Edit: here is the Exports table of the file at c:\MinGW\bin\libintl-8.dll

```
[Ordinal/Name Pointer] Table
        [   0] __printf__
        [   1] _get_output_format
        [   2] _nl_expand_alias
        [   3] _nl_explode_name
        [   4] _nl_find_domain
        [   5] _nl_find_msg
        [   6] _nl_language_preferences_default
        [   7] _nl_load_domain
         ...   ...
```

Answer (score 10):

On my system, I fixed this by reordering my system `PATH` envvar so that `c:\MinGW\bin` would show up before `%GTK_BASEPATH%\bin`. That way, the correct `libintl-8.dll` that `as.exe` wanted would be found, even when GCC launches it from `c:\MinGW\bin\mingw32\bin` instead of `c:\MinGW\bin`. Otherwise, it would try to link against the one shipped with some GTK+ SDK which did not have all of the required symbols, I assume. Also, in my case, the dialog box complained that `as.exe` was missing the symbol when really the `libintl-8.dll` that the dynamic linker decided to try to use was at fault.

Too bad there aren’t more packages installable via `mingw-get` that actually share shared objects instead of each SDK shipping its own installer along with its own incompatible variants of the DLLs…

Comment: You are a genius, have lost 2 hours solving this!

Answer (score 7):

I do the same thing. Rename `c:\mingw\mwingw32` to `c:\mingw\mingw32old` and it works
(Windows XP). In Windows 7 64-bit I have not had this problem.

Comment: It would be lovely to know why this is necessary or if a more elegant fix is available.

Comment: and also must run command prompt as administrator in windows 7 32-bit

Answer (score 4):

I experienced a similar problem.  In my case the error appeared in a dialog box, rather than in the console output from the compiler.  This indicates that it's actually a problem with execution of the compiler, rather than with the compilation.  Try adding `-v` to the gcc command to see what sub-commands its executing.  In my case it was an issue with it trying to execute `as.exe` from `MinGW/mingw32/bin` instead of `MinGW/bin` (the libintl DLL doesn't exist in the former location).  I renamed the `MinGW/mingw32` folder to prevent it being found and the compilation succeeded.  Not sure why it was looking in this location though.

Ultimately I fixed this by doing a fresh install of MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

Here how it should be.

libintl-8.dll 0.8.1

```
Export Table:
  Name:                          libintl-8.dll
  Time Date Stamp:               0x4EA19844 (21.10.2011 17:05:24)
  Version:                       0.00
  Ordinal Base:                  1
  Number of Functions:           84
  Number of Names:               84

  Ordinal   Entry Point   Name
        1   0x00009124    __printf__
        2   0x000105B8    _get_output_format
        .   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But knowing how it should be doesn't tell me why the DLL included in the download/install package isn't the one the compiler wants or what I'm supposed to do about it.

Comment: This may sound crazy, but I notice that my objdump ordinals are zero-based and yours are not.  Is it possible that there is an actual discrepancy, or is it a matter of how the tool displays the list?

Comment: @JoeDavis : Try and you will see : [libintl-8.dll](http://moskito-x.de/stack/libintl-8.dll)

Comment: I replaced my file with yours and got the exact same error.  Here's my build command: `gcc -o helloworld.exe HELLOWORLD.m -I /GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L /GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -std=c99 -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString`

Comment: @JoeDavis : for a simple Helloworld you usually do not need `libintl` . We can not see your code. And please put your build command in your question, not in a comment.